# jsMockito: How to run callback sended to mock?

Tags: javascript, callback, jsmockito

I am learning how to use jsMockito to write perfect code. So, could you give me any idea on how to run callback which is provided to service?

Here is my class:

```
function MyClass(service) {
    this.service = service;
}

MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    this.service.doIt(function() {
        console.log("How to run this function while running tests?");
    })
}
```

And here is my test:

```
var MyClassTest = TestCase("MyClassTest");

MyClassTest.prototype.testMyClass = function() {
    this.service = mock(Service);
    this.myClass = new MyClass(this.service);
    this.myClass.doSomething();
}
```

So, I need to see the log message:
`"How to run this function while running tests?"`

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution.

We need to create `doItCallback`:

```
function MyClass(service) {
    this.service = service;
}

MyClass.prototype.doItCallback = function() {
    console.log("How to run this function while running tests?");
}

MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    this.service.doIt(this.doItCallback);
}
```

Also we need to update the mock:

```
var MyClassTest = TestCase("MyClassTest");

MyClassTest.prototype.testMyClass = function() {
    this.service = mock(Service);
    this.myClass = new MyClass(this.service);
    var myClass = this.myClass;
    when(this.service).doIt().then(function() {
        myClass.doItCallback();
    });
    this.myClass.doSomething();
}
```